# Calculus Derivatives Problem

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

Can anyone find infinitely many pairs of functions f(x), g(x) such that (f(x)*g(x))' = f'(x)*g'(x)

Also, neither f'(x) nor g'(x) can equal 0. (They can't be constants)

Edit by Igor Minevich:
This was an extra credit question I assigned in my calculus class, and it was asked here by a student of mine. Somehow we should take care to make sure these questions don't get answered until the context and the experience level of the person who asked is determined. Thank you for closing the question!

Comment: On which domain? What have you tried?

Comment: Does the "$*$" denote convolution?

Answer (score 2):

You want 
$$
f^\prime g + f g^\prime = f^\prime g^\prime
$$
An idea is to see if "simple" choices of $g$ would work, since then you get a differential equation in $f$ only. *(See below for more details and an example; stop here if you want to try by yourself before)*

---

For the sake of trying, take $g$ to be the simplest possible given the constraints, say $g(x)=x$. So $g^\prime = 1$. (The goal is to see if it works, since it's simple to handle; if not, then another attempt will have to be made.)
$$
xf^\prime(x) + f(x) = f^\prime(x), \forall x
$$
You can check that on the domain $(-\infty, 1)$, $f(x)=\frac{c}{1-x}$ works. (for any $c$).

Comment: As in Michael Burr's answer (below or above), another natural choice for "simple $g$" would be $g(x)=e^{a x}$ for some constant $a$, since then $g^\prime$ is also very nice and you get convenient cancellations in the first equation, leading to an easy-to-handle ODE.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $ab=a+b$ (there are infinitely many such choices, for example, when $a=b=2$).  Then let $f(x)=e^{ax}$ and $g(x)=e^{bx}$.

Then, $fg=e^{(a+b)x}$ and $(fg)'=(a+b)e^{(a+b)x}$.  On the other hand, $f'=ae^{ax}$ and $g'=be^{bx}$ so $f'g'=abe^{(a+b)x}$.  Since $ab=a+b$, by assumption, $(fg)'=f'g'$.